# Using onclick event store data of extra field in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, input, onclick

I am trying to store data which is the only show if someone clicks on an online payment. Its easy in PHP, but in Codeigniter it's not working.

```
<div class="radio">
                <?php echo form_radio('bank', 'Online Payment', FALSE, 
   ['onclick'=>"add_fields()"]); ?><?php echo form_label('Online Payment', 
  'bank');?>
            <br>    <?php echo form_radio('bank', 'Cash', FALSE); ?><?php 
   echo form_label('Cash', 'bank');?>
    </div>
```

& here is the script:

```
  <script>
  function add_fields()
  {
   var d = document.getElementById("content");

   d.innerHTML += "Enter Bank Details<br /> <input 
    type='text',name='bankdetail'/>";

 }
</script>
<p id="content"></p>
```

I try to use:

```
 d.innerHTML += "Enter Bank Details<br />  <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'bankdetail']);?>";
```

but its not show the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tell us more about the problem?

are you going inside function add_fields() ?

Also, just try to put

```
<p id="content"></p>
```

and then this,

```
  <script>
  function add_fields()
  {
   var d = document.getElementById("content");

   d.innerHTML += "Enter Bank Details<br /> <input 
    type='text' name='bankdetail'/>"; // REMOVE THE COMMA FROM HERE

 }
</script>
```

remove the comma from innerHTML line, Do let us know if it still doesn't work.